# Ambiguous use of operator '<' when comparing Doubles and Integers in Swift

Tags: swift

Why does swift behave so weird when comparing Doubles and Integers?

Consider the following code for repl/playground:

```
12>12.0        //false 

13 > 12.0        //true
13.0 > 12        //true

13 >= 12.0        //true
13 <= 12.0        //false

12.0 < 13        //Error: Ambiguous  use of operator '<'
12 < 13.0       //Error: Ambiguous  use of operator '<'
```

What exactly is Ambiguous in the use of operator here?

The debug console output is not especially helpful either:

```
error: ambiguous use of operator '<'
12 < 13.0
   ^

Foundation.RunLoop:18:32: note: found this candidate
            public static func < (lhs: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, rhs: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) -> Bool
                               ^

Foundation.Decimal:4:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func < (lhs: Decimal, rhs: Decimal) -> Bool
                       ^

Foundation.OperationQueue:18:32: note: found this candidate
            public static func < (lhs: OperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, rhs: OperationQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) -> Bool
                               ^

Dispatch.DispatchQueue:22:32: note: found this candidate
            public static func < (lhs: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, rhs: DispatchQueue.SchedulerTimeType.Stride) -> Bool
```

---

**UPD:** Just to clarify, I know that I can cast values explicitly.

The question is why exactly does the language behave this way and was is it designed to behave this way with `<` operator?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the _why_ here, but you should just cast to disambiguate. All those will work: `12 < Float(13.0)`,
`Float(12.0) < 13`,
`12 < Double(13.0)`,
`Double(12.0) < 13`,
`12 < Decimal(13.0)`,
`Decimal(12.0) < 13`,
`Decimal(12) < 13.0`,
`12.0 < Decimal(13)`

Comment: I guess all the types in error messages conform to expressibleBy… for both integers and floats and they all have a custom < operator defined for Int and Double.

Comment: @Cœur I know that I can cast, but I wonder why is the language designed like this?

Comment: Note that your examples aren’t really meaningful since in a real world scenario at least one of the values would have been replaced by a variable that gives the compiler some help in determining how to perform the comparison

Answer (score 2):

I think operators >, >=, =, != were implemented by Swift's cast mechanism to compare. Operator <, == are two special operators which must be of the same type to compare.

I found a Swift Document, which has some information about it. [Compare](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable)

Comment: But why exactly was it designed like this? `==` somewhat makes sense, but I find the difference between `<` and `>` to be weird

Comment: I know a litter about assembly, in [mips sheet](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) just has less than and equal operators to comparing. I think it is reason.

Comment: No this isn't correct, you can use < for different types if the compiler can cast one of them. so `Float(4) < 3` is fine since the compiler can cast from Int to Float

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's not quite correct. In your example, the left hand side is unambiguously `Float`. The compiler infers that the right hand side must also be a `Float` or an error. `3` is an integer literal and `Float` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. The compiler doesn't know how to cast an `Int` to a `Float` it knows how to construct a `Float` from an integer literal. `Float(4) < Int(3)` is illegal

Comment: @JeremyP Ok, sorry for my use of the English language then but I am always thinking of it as casting when the compiler automatically changes a type to another even if converting or creating is the correct term.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No problem, it's not a big issue, but an integer literal isn't an `Int`: it is whatever type is demanded by the context. Understanding the nuance helps to explain things like why `4.0 < 3` compiles and `Float(4.0) < Int(3)` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is you are not comparing `Double`s to `Int`s. All of your examples compare two literals and I expect that Swift is inferring the types to be `Double` always. You can verify this with the following

```
let a: Int = 12
a > 12.0          // Error: Binary operator > cannot be applied to Int and Double
```

The second thing to note is that the problem goes away if you do not import `Foundation`.

What is actually happening is that `Foundation` introduces several overloads for `<` in order to make a number of Foundation types conform to [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) and the compiler no longer knows which type to infer when compiling comparisons of literals (it must also be making these types conform to `ExpressibleByFloatliteral` and `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`) .

The reason that it is only for `<` is probably due to the fact that you only need to implement that operator to conform to `Comparable` and there are default implementations for the other comparison operators in an extension to the protocol.

Comment: Could you please expand on the last paragraph? Or could you please give a link to some explanation about "you only need to implement that operator to conform to Comparable"?

Comment: @DataGreed Types that conform to `Comparable` implement all the comparison operators: `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`. However there is an extension to `Comparable` that provides default implementation for  `>`, `<=`, `>=`,`!=` in terms of `<` and `==`. So, to conform, all you need to do is implement  `<` and `==` and you get the other operators for free.